# JavaScript binding for AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bind

I'm trying to bind the AJAX callback function to a certain scope, what am I doing wrong?

here is my code:

```
var MainApp = {
    files:{
        "A":{
            url:"files/a.json",
            content:""
        },
        "B":{
            url:"files/b.json",
            content:""
        }
    },
    init:function () {
        this.loadFiles();
    },
    loadFiles:function () {
        for (var i in this.files) {
            var f = function (data) {
                console.log("callback",this);
            };
            console.log("binding",this);
            f.bind(this);
            $.get(this.files[i].url, f);
        }
    }
};

$(function () {
    MainApp.init();
});
```

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: What scope are you trying to give the callback?

Comment: thanks for the reply, the problem was that the "this" on the f callback was the window.
what I wanted is that when the callback is called, the "this" would be my MainApp object and not the window ... problem was solved ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f.bind(this);
```

`Function#bind` doesn't alter the original function, it returns a new function bound to the parameter. You probably meant:

```
f= f.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using call:

```
that = this;
$.get(this.files[i].url, function() {
   f.call(that)
});
```